# gridview event: no overload matches delegate

Tags: asp.net

Here's the problem with the gridview as I have it:

in the aspx:

`<asp: GridView..... ID="MyGrid" AllowSorting = "True" OnSorting = "SortMyGrid"`>

in the code behind:

```
protected void SortMyGrid(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
     DataTable TheGridData =  MyGrid.DataSource as DataTable;
}
```

And then when I run the code:
No overload for 'SortMyGrid' matches delegate

What's causing this problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the wrong EventArgs you need to be using `GridViewSortEventArgs` not `GridViewPageEventArgs`

[MSDN Article GridView Sorting Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.sorting.aspx)